# How to write an if statement with two conditional expressions?

Tags: php, validation, syntax-error, conditional-statements, strlen

I was working on a login form and the session of it. Now I'm getting this error:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected 'strlen' (T_STRING) in **/home/xxx/domains/xxx/public_html/server/include/session.php** on line **130**

This is the line of the error:

```
if(!$subuser strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0){
```

This is the whole code:

```
function login($subuser, $subpass, $subremember){
    global $database, $form;  //The database and form object
    /* Username error checking */

    $field = "user";  //Use field name for username
    if(!$subuser strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0){
        $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
    }
    else{
        /* Check if username is not alphanumeric */
        if(!eregi("^([0-9a-z])*$", $subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax: `(!$subuser strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0)`. It can probably also be written as `(strlen(trim($subuser)) == 0)`

Comment: once you fixed that, you'll have another barrier to break; `eregi()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two checks upon `$subuser` in the first expression -- and if you did, you should be using `||` to separate them.

Use `ctype_alnum()` instead of `preg_match()` to check for alphanumeric characters.

```
function login($subuser, $subpass, $subremember){
    global $database, $form;  //The database and form object

    $field = "user";  //Use field name for username
    if (!strlen($subuser = trim($subuser))) {
        $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
    //} elseif (!preg_match('/^[\da-z]+$/i', $subuser)) {
    } elseif (!ctype_alnum($subuser)) {
        $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
    }
}
```

- the design logic in the first conditional is to update the `$subuser` value then check its length so that the second conditional doesn't receive a string with leading or trailing spaces.

Here's a [demonstration](https://3v4l.org/MF7SZ).

Answer (score 0):

This line of code isn't valid syntax:

```
if(!$subuser strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0){
```

Consider changing it to:

```
if(!strlen(trim($subuser))) {
```